# Fullcalendar remember days selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar to select the holidays, at now is working fine until the selection.

I can select multiple days but when i change the month and i go back Fullcalendar didnt remember the days selected.

I want to be able to select all days and then push the Submit button so i can save all days in one click.

My javascript code is:

```
var events= [{
        id : 0,
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(2016, 3, 5)
    }];
    var i=1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: events,
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                // change the day's background and save the day selected
                $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
                var temp={id: i, title: 'Holidays', start: new Date(date)};
                i=i+1;
                events.push(temp);

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', temp );
            }

        });

    });
```

any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a flag to make the event permanent as below :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     events: events,
     dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
         var temp={id: i, title: 'Holidays', start: new Date(date)};
         i=i+1;
         events.push(temp);

         $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', temp, true );
    }
});
```

You can also add "backgroundColor" to your event to identify your selection, as setting the table cell's background colour will be lost when you move back and forth.

```
var temp={id: i, title: 'Holidays', start: new Date(date), backgroundColor: 'green'};
```